# Download file with apache chemistry php client

Tags: alfresco, cmis, apache-chemistry

I need to know what I've to do if I want to download a cmis:documento that I've in my repositorio with Apache Chemistry Php client.

I've one file, "Test.txt" in Sitios space...
I want download Test.txt with browser...

My code:

```
$client = new CMISService('http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/cmis/versions/1.1/atom', 'admin', 'admin');
$path = '/Sitios';
$directorio = $client->getObjectByPath($path);

$objs = $client->getChildren($directorio->id);
foreach ($objs->objectList as $obj)
{
    var_dump ($obj);
}
```

In $obj I've:

```
 array (size=32)
      'alfcmis:nodeRef' => string 'workspace://SpacesStore/c3c903fe-86b6-4db0-8cb2-d5c5dbe913c7' (length=60)
      'cmis:isImmutable' => string 'false' (length=5)
      'cmis:versionLabel' => string '1.0' (length=3)
      'cmis:objectTypeId' => string 'cmis:document' (length=13)
      'cmis:description' => string 'descripcion del fichero' (length=23)
      'cmis:createdBy' => string 'admin' (length=5)
      'cmis:checkinComment' => null
      'cmis:creationDate' => string '2016-02-15T01:25:12.76+01:00' (length=28)
      'cmis:isMajorVersion' => string 'true' (length=4)
      'cmis:contentStreamFileName' => string 'Fichero de texto plano' (length=22)
      'cmis:name' => string 'Fichero de texto plano' (length=22)
      'cmis:isLatestVersion' => string 'true' (length=4)
      'cmis:lastModificationDate' => string '2016-02-15T01:25:12.76+01:00' (length=28)
      'cmis:contentStreamLength' => string '21' (length=2)
      'cmis:objectId' => string 'c3c903fe-86b6-4db0-8cb2-d5c5dbe913c7;1.0' (length=40)
      'cmis:lastModifiedBy' => string 'admin' (length=5)
      'cmis:secondaryObjectTypeIds' => string 'P:rn:renditioned' (length=16)
      'cmis:contentStreamId' => string 'store://2016/2/15/1/25/c36a749d-43f1-4e31-b46a-de66b4f5634d.bin' (length=63)
      'cmis:contentStreamMimeType' => string 'text/plain' (length=10)
      'cmis:baseTypeId' => string 'cmis:document' (length=13)
      'cmis:changeToken' => null
      'cmis:isPrivateWorkingCopy' => string 'false' (length=5)
      'cmis:versionSeriesCheckedOutBy' => null
      'cmis:isVersionSeriesCheckedOut' => string 'false' (length=5)
      'cmis:versionSeriesId' => string 'c3c903fe-86b6-4db0-8cb2-d5c5dbe913c7' (length=36)
      'cmis:isLatestMajorVersion' => string 'true' (length=4)
      'cmis:versionSeriesCheckedOutId' => null
      'cm:title' => string 'Titulo del fichero' (length=18)
      'cm:description' => string 'descripcion del fichero' (length=23)
      'app:editInline' => string 'true' (length=4)
      'cm:lastThumbnailModification' => string 'pdf:1455495914744' (length=17)
      '' => string 'Titulo del fichero' (length=18)
  public 'renditions' =>
```

What I've to do to create a link to download the file?
I don't want to use webscript...

I think that I've to use getContentStream($obj->id) ¿really?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your document mime type and what you are willing to do with, it can be slightly different, but basically [this](https://chemistry.apache.org/java/developing/guide.html#reading-the-contents-of-a-document-object) is what you need to do, if you were using java:

> ```
>   // Get the contents of the file
>     Document doc = (Document) session.getObject(id);
>     ContentStream contentStream = doc.getContentStream(); // returns null if the document has no content
>     if (contentStream != null) {
>         String content = getContentAsString(contentStream);
>         System.out.println("Contents of " + filename + " are: " + content);
>     } else {
>         System.out.println("No content.");
>     }
>
>     ...
>
>     /**
>      * Helper method to get the contents of a stream
>      * 
>      * @param stream
>      * @return
>      * @throws IOException
>      */
>     private static String getContentAsString(ContentStream stream) throws IOException {
>         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
>         Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream.getStream(), "UTF-8");
>
>         try {
>             final char[] buffer = new char[4 * 1024];
>             int b;
>             while (true) {
>                 b = reader.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
>                 if (b > 0) {
>                     sb.append(buffer, 0, b);
>                 } else if (b == -1) {
>                     break;
>                 }
>             }
>         } finally {
>             reader.close();
>         }
>
>         return sb.toString();
>     }
> ```

but since you are on PHP, I guess you should be replicating the same logic with [php api fuctions](https://chemistry.apache.org/php/docs/atom/classes/CMISService.html#getContentStream), so basically `$client->getContentStream($objId);` should return the file content as string.